# Simplify and solve an N-term exponential equation

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How does one express this sum into Mathematica:

$$10^{k-1} + 10^{k-2} +....+ 10 + 1$$

I think I have to use the Sum function? Then run it over N=K..1? But then I want to substitute and evaluate it for various k's.

Ok once I get that input correctly, my ultimate goal is to Simplify this for P, Q, R, and k positive integers:

$$P(10^{2k-1} + 10^{2k-2} + 10^{2k-3} +....+ 10^k + 10^{k-1} + ... +10 + 1) - Q(10^{k-1} + 10^{k-2} +....+ 10 + 1) = R^2(10^{k-1} + 10^{k-2} +....+ 10 + 1)^2 $$

I need to have Mathematica Simplify that, then run it over some large values of the 4 variables and try and see which ones solve the equality.

P.S. in a Nutshell what that is saying is this: Find me a series of 2k-length repeated digits then subtract another series of k-length digits from it, that will result in a new set of k-length digits squared - the multiplier of which is also squared.
So say for a fake example: $$444444-222=2^2(333)^2$$  I just made that up to show you what it would look like. That equality is 666 off! Just notice how the first number has 6 digits and the next 2 have half (3 digits), etc. In this case P=4, Q=2, R=2, and k=3 . I want Mathematical to go over all k's (say for k from 1 to 10000) and give me exact solutions and tell me for what values of P, Q, and R, the equality is satisfied over that range of k.

Comment: The top sum is easily expressed as `Sum[10^n, {n, 0, k - 1}]` which has a closed form $(-1 + 10^k)/9$

Comment: Clever. Mathematica simplifies that to a closed form regardless of whether we surround it by Simplify[] or not. This is another way of saying a bunch of 1's lined up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First notice that `Sum[10^n, {n, 0, k - 1}]` is `1/9 (-1 + 10^k)`, so you can make a closed form.

This generates at most 20 solutions for each $k$ from 1, 100. Change those numbers if you have more time:

```
eqn = FullSimplify[p (-1 + 10^(2 k))/9 - q (-1 + 10^k)/9 == r^2 ((-1 + 10^k)/9)^2]

Table[{i, FindInstance[(eqn /. k -> i) && 1 <= p <= 9 && 1 <= q <= 9 && 
    1 <= r <= 9, {p, q, r}, PositiveIntegers, 20]}
 , {i, 1, 100}]
```

The equation is always satisfied by:

```
eqn /. {p -> 1, q -> 2, r -> 3}
eqn /. {p -> 4, q -> 8, r -> 6}
```

... for any $k\ge1$. For example with $k=3$ we have: $$444444 - 888 = 6^2 (111)^2 \\
111111 - 222 = 3^2 (111)^2$$

---

You could also have done this in a much more 'brute-force' way without the closed form simplifications, which is possible because there are only a small number of tuples for $p,q,r$, but I don't know why you'd ever want to do this:

```
(* create all possible assignments of p,q,r *)
assignments = Thread[{p, q, r} -> #] & /@ Tuples[Range[9], {3}];

eqn = (p*Sum[10^n, {n, 0, 2 k - 1}] - q*Sum[10^n, {n, 0, k - 1}] == 
    r^2*Sum[10^n, {n, 0, k - 1}]^2);

(* for every i, 1..10, replace k with i and perform each assignment, selecting the assignments that satisfy the equation *) 
ParallelTable[
 DeleteDuplicates[
   Select[assignments,
     ReplaceAll[eqn /. k -> i, #] &
   ], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this @Flinty! Let me have a detailed look and get back to you later today. Cheers

Comment: Ok @flinty i executed the Table[] and got pages of values out. All of which are in terms of p,q, and r. What do you do with that next? How do I see the zeros, and how do you get those 2 solutions above? Plz walk me through in case I missed something, Thanks.

Comment: And what if the series was in such a way that it did not have a closed-form equivalent. I assume we could have still done the same thing using Sum[] throughout the steps?

Comment: Lastly, I simplified it manually by hand, but get this: (take a note that 10^2k-1=(10^k-1)(10^k+1) ....then plug it in and simplify (all (10^k-1)/9's cancel on both sides and we end up with):  P(10^k+1)-(R^2/9)(10^k-1)-Q==0  but this doesn't look like what it gives us.

Comment: @Steve237 _...pages of values out..._  those are the solutions, the values of k and the assignments to p,q,r that satisfy the equation you posted. _How do I see the zeros..._ : the `eqn` after simplification is of the form `lhs == 0` so to get the lhs just do `First[eqn]`. You can then plug in values for p,q,r that you got in the table: this for example `First[eqn] /. {p -> 4, q -> 8, r -> 6}` should give zero.

Comment: check my output. I have a few warnings. Did you get same thing? [my output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/112GOvalU1vwuI9pRGxB4juARwIjYYK0c/view?usp=sharing) I still do not see solutions in the output. Where does it tell me 4,8,6 is a solution? Or am i supposed to try out all p's, q's and r's to see which one will lead to ==0 ? Thx

Comment: Regarding your second answer, no i did not mean to do it in brute force method. I meant to say what IF there was no closed-form reduction - in which case i would have no choice but to.

Comment: Hi @flinty : I'm pretty sure my output is not showing any triplet set solutions for p,q,r at all. Take a look at my link above. Did you get that, or are my settings not right in Mathematica? Thx

Comment: I got it. I have no idea why but my version of Mathematica, which is 11.3.0.0, for some reason is not happy with the PositiveIntegers which you chose. I changed it to Integers and it worked. Any idea why that is? [new result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gAezz-JrcS3SvgXG3ICOHMQUysqBvnAq/view)

Comment: PositiveIntegers is new in v12+